# Configure SonarQube in VSTS Hosted agent or as an Azure PaaS for CI

Tags: azure, sonarqube, continuous-integration, azure-devops

As part of including SonarQube in our CI pipeline for code coverage , we created a SonarQube server endpoint pointing to SonarQube server hosted in Azure VM. But we are in the verge of removing our dependency on IaaS, so is there any other alternatives for hosting SonarQube server .

Has anyone tried the same or have similar experiences?

Comment: See: https://about.sonarcloud.io/

Comment: PS: requesting tools or alternative tools is officially offtopic for Stack Overflow. To learn more about the right topics for Stack Overflow check out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The VSTS Hosted agent isn’t including SonarQube server, so you can’t configure SonarQube in VSTS Hosted agent.

You can use [sonarcloud](https://about.sonarcloud.io/) or setup a sonarqube server on your server machine.

Comment: Sonarcloud is for analysing open source projects i guess.But in our case it's not an open source project. By setting up sonarqube server in your server machine you meant in Azure VM's?

Comment: @LakshmyR You can buy the license for private project https://about.sonarcloud.io/how-it-works/. Regarding sonarqube server, the Azure VM is ok.